# Select XML nodes that contain substring in VB.net axis notation

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Using the VB.net axis operators (..././@)  how can I select/iterate nodes with a specific substring.

E.g.

Take some XML snippet like this:

```
<Route name="Fly from London Heathrow" distance="1192.88" duration="355">
 <IndicativePrice price="163" currency="USD" isFreeTransfer="0"/>
 <Stop name="Surbiton" pos="51.39301,-0.30677" kind="town"/>
 <Stop name="Kingston Upon Thames, Kingston" pos="51.41182,-0.3006" kind="station"/>
 <Stop name="London Heathrow" pos="51.47034,-0.45342" kind="airport" code="LHR"/>
 <Stop name="Barcelona" pos="41.30373,2.07315" kind="airport" code="BCN"/>
 <Stop name="Barcelona" pos="41.38702,2.17004" kind="city"/>
 [SO-point 1]
 <TransitSegment kind="bus" subkind="bus" vehicle="bus" isMajor="0" isImperial="1" ..."></TransitSegment>
 <TransitSegment kind="bus" subkind="bus" vehicle="bus" isMajor="0" isImperial="1" distance="18.4 ..."></TransitSegment>
 <FlightSegment kind="flight" isMajor="1" distance="1146.72" duration="120" sCode="LHR" tCode="BCN"></FlightSegment>
 <TransitSegment kind="train" subkind="train" vehicle="train" isMajor="0" isImperial="0" distance="25.07" duration="25" sName="Aeropuerto de Prat" sPos="41.30426,2.07352" sCode="7172400" tName="Barcelona P.Gracia" tPos="41.38725,2.16866" tCode="7100063" path=".."></TransitSegment>
 [SO-point 2]
</Route>
```

I can iterate the Stops like this:

```
For Each routeStop In route.<ns:Stop>
                Dim nextStop As New r2rSearchResponseRoutes.r2rSearchResponseStops
                nextStop.kind = routeStop.@kind
                nextStop.name = routeStop.@name
                nextStop.code = routeStop.@code
                nextStop.pos = routeStop.@pos

                nextRoute.listOfStops.Add(nextStop)
            Next
```

How would I select against any node that had a substring e.g. "Segment" in the node name like the example above?  Shown in above from [SO-point 1] to  [SO-point 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LINQ methods to filter XML nodes, for example :

```
For Each s As XElement In route.Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName.Contains("Segment"))
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString())
Next
```